Airflow UI doesn't show dags
I'm using airflow for an enough time, but this is the first time, when I don't know why it's not working correctly.
I have my django app and airflow as a scheduler (both on docker), it's working good when i was using one postgres db for both of them, but when i tried to split them and make on two different clusters i faced a problem: airflow see my dags, but doesn't show in ui:
it sees that there is 311 dags, but also says 'no result'

I checked me connection with db: psql -h host -U username -p port -d dbname, for both (django db and airflow db) it's working on, also in airflow db in table dag there is 311 elements as it has to be (i tried to delete them and do 'airflow db init')
Logs is clear for 3 services of airflow in docker: worker, scheduler and webserver (of course after all my changes i did 'docker-compose restart worker scheduler webserver' or 'down --volumes' and 'up --build -d')
I correctly set db's parameters in Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml and airflow.cfg
When i try in some airflow's container run 'airflow dags list' it shows them correctly
I thought problem may be in db connections in dags.py, where i setup django ("import django; django.setup()") and it could broke airflow's connection to db and write dag's info in db not correctly, but i tried use another ORM and close connection at the end of the file, so problem didn't appear
The last i can think about is not correct dags (but still don't understand, that it's working in one db on localhost, but not in two different at clusters)
Here is i import django
Here is example of generating dynamic dags (i also tried change 'start_date' to datetime(2024, 1, 1))


I also tried create new dagfile with dag on PythonOperator with no any connections on dbs with func which returns sum of 2 nums and it was in ui

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
